# Angular Websocket Closes Immediately after send() is called

Tags: angular, websocket

Below contains my sendMessage() function where I am trying to JSON.stringify() an object to then be able to call this.ws.send(), with that JSON string. Whenever I try to send a stringified object, which is really just a string, my websocket closes immediately after the ws.send is called. On the other hand, if I just provide the ws.send() with the content of my message (just the text message sent), then it works fine.

```html
    ngOnInit() {
      this.messageForm = new FormGroup({
        message: new FormControl('')
      })
      this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.chatroomId = params['id']
        console.log(this.chatroomId)
      });
      this.store
      .pipe(
          select(getCurrUser)
      ).subscribe(data =>  {
          this.user = data
          this.userId = this.user.user_id || ""
          this.userType = this.user.user_category
          console.log(this.userId)
      })
      this.chatroomService.getChatroomsByUserId(this.userId).subscribe(data => {
        this.chatrooms = data

      })
      if (this.chatroomId) {
        this.chatroomService.getChatroomById(this.chatroomId).subscribe(chatroom => {
          this.currChatroom = chatroom
          this.user1 = chatroom.user1
          this.user2 = chatroom.user2
          this.user1_id = chatroom.user1_id
          this.user2_id = chatroom.user2_id
          if (this.user1_id == this.userId) {
            this.otherUser = this.user2
            this.otherUserId = this.user2_id
          } else {
            this.otherUser = this.user1
            this.otherUserId = this.user1_id
          }
        })
      }
      if (this.chatroomId) {
        this.chatroomService.getMessagesByChatroomId(this.chatroomId).subscribe(messages => {
          console.log(messages)
          this.messages = messages.reverse()
        })
        this.url = "ws://" + "localhost:8080" + "/api/" + this.chatroomId + "/ws";
        console.log(this.url)
        this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url)
        console.log(this.ws)
        this.ws.onopen = () => console.log('websocket connected!');
        this.ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
          const socket = msg.target as WebSocket;
          if (socket.url !== this.url) return socket.close();
          const d = JSON.parse(msg.data);
          console.log(d)
          this.messages = [...this.messages, d];
        }
        this.ws.onclose = () => console.log("websocket closed");
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => this.ws.close())
      }
  }

    sendMessage() {
      const sender = this.user
      const id = this.userId
      const msg = this.messageForm.get('message').value
      var msgStr: string  = JSON.stringify({
        message: msg,
        sender_id: id,
        chatroom_id: this.chatroomId,
        sender: sender,
        timestamp: "Just now"
      })
      this.ws.send(msgStr)
      this.chatroomService.sendMessage(this.messageForm.get('message').value, this.userId, this.currChatroom.chatroom_id).subscribe(message => {
        console.log(message)
        this.messageForm.reset()
      })
    }

 





}
```

As soon as this.ws.send() is called, the websocket seems to close; however, when I change my sendMessage function to just send the message text and not a JSON string, it works. Thus, this following code block does not cause errors; however, I need to pass additional data such as sender_id.

```html
sendMessage() {
      const sender = this.user
      const id = this.userId
      const msg = this.messageForm.get('message').value
      this.ws.send(msg)
      this.chatroomService.sendMessage(this.messageForm.get('message').value, this.userId,       this.currChatroom.chatroom_id).subscribe(message => {
        console.log(message)
        this.messageForm.reset()
      })
    }
```

Comment: The code looks fine and like you've deducted yourself sending a string or an object using JSON stringify should make no difference. What is your backend like? What's receiving these messages. Maybe problem is in the backend, maybe backend can't handle such messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that when stringifying my JSON Object, the sender attribute was a defined User type that for whatever reason, was causing issues and perhaps not being correctly handled by my Go backend API.

The following code with sender: sender is the culprit, as the sender value is a User object.

```html
var msgStr: string  = JSON.stringify({
        message: msg,
        sender_id: id,
        chatroom_id: this.chatroomId,
        sender: sender,
        timestamp: "Just now"
      })
```

I fixed this by simply doing the following:

```html
var msgStr: string  = JSON.stringify({
        message: msg,
        sender: {
          first_name: sender.first_name,
          last_name: sender.last_name,
          user_id: sender.user_id
        },
        chatroom_id: this.chatroomId,
        timestamp: "Just now"
      })
```

I only provided the object with the necessary data from my sender User object, which was really just the first name, last name, and user_id.